# How do i declare an object within the parameters of my contructor of a different class? (C++)

Tags: c++

For an assignment, i am writing a class called patientType, within patientType i want the constructor to store certain variables such as the patients date of birth, and i wish for the dates to be objects of dateType (another class in my code) so for my constructor, i have:

```
patientType(string first = "", string last="", string ID="", int old = 0,dateType dob, string physician ="", dateType admisDate, dateType disDate);
```

---

but am getting the error message:

```
"patientType.h:11:1: error: default argument missing for parameter 5 of ‘patientType::patientType(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string, int, dateType, std::__cxx11::string, dateType, dateType)’"
```

i have tried providing default arguments for dateTypes constructor

Comment: Default parameters can only appear at the end. You either have to make all your parameters have a default, or rearrange them so the ones that do have a default, occur at the end.

Comment: and for arguments sake, its a lot of error messages all that look like that one

Comment: @ChrisMM that worked thankyou!! ive spent a good 3 hours trying to debug this